# Using C# to run a PowerShell script

Tags: c#, powershell

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddScript("[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback+={$true}");
```

Is that right?
What's the next step?

Comment: [command.Invoke() ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144526(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but command does not have Invoike() method.

Comment: Yes, it should be `powershell.Invoke()` after you've done what Coincoin suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscommand%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
PSCommand command = new PSCommand(); 
command.AddScript( 
    "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback+={$true}"
); 

PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Commands = cmd;

var results = powershell.Invoke();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `powershell.Commands = cmd;` be `powershell.Commands = command;` ?

Comment: Note that PowerShell is IDisposable, so it should be in a using block. Also note that you may have multiple versions of System.Management.Automation.dll on your system, and you need the PowerShell 2.0 or higher ones for these classes. On my system the correct file was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll - the one in Program Files was old.